# Should we have bloomberg terminal/actual software in order to access its api in Python

Tags: python, bloomberg

I wanted to check if we require  bloomberg terminal/actual software in order to access its api in Python.
Example, I am a new user and do not have Bloomberg terminal. So can I Access its API  in Python?

Tried reading this link [https://www.bloomberg.com/company/careers/working-here/employee-resources/new-hire-tech/bloomberg-anywhere-access-bba/#:~:text=Download%20Citrix%20software,Google%20Chrome%20for%20Mac%20OS](https://www.bloomberg.com/company/careers/working-here/employee-resources/new-hire-tech/bloomberg-anywhere-access-bba/#:%7E:text=Download%20Citrix%20software,Google%20Chrome%20for%20Mac%20OS).
But need someone who can guide me here?

Comment: Please refrain from asking the same question twice.

Comment: No No, this question is different. I meant, should we have a terminal to use API or even non-terminal user can access the API

Comment: You can download the API for free, but to do anything meaningful with it (i.e. retrieve data) you need a subscription.

Comment: Thanks. But i do not see any API for free. Can you share the link if any for reference :)

Comment: Here: https://www.bloomberg.com/professional/support/api-library/
You can download the Java/C++/Python API and the docs, and start coding but you won't  be able to connect to the API or retrieve data.